# Using a reference to the main Window from a static class - Good practice?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF application with the main Window class called MainWindow. 
Since I have other classes that need to access the Dispatcher of the UI thread to update bounded lists, I found this solution:

I made a static class:

```
 static class UI 
    {
        static public MainWindow window;
    }
```

And added the following line in the app constructor:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            UI.window = this;
...
```

Now I can access the components of my GUI everywhere by using `UI.window.Dispatcher.Invoke().`

The question is - is this a good programming practice? 
Is there a better method of doing so?

Thank you

**Update:**

I seem to get the exception thrown only when I update an ObservableCollection which is bound to a 3rd party control. I have another static OC bound to a listbox (to display updated messages) and I can update that one from other threads without using the dispatcher. 
How come?
Is it because its a static OC or is it related to the control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its only about the dispatcher, you can do this

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action)delegate()
    {
    });
```

Comment: This seems to be the easier way to access the main dispatcher without keeping static references

Answer (score 4):

> Since I have other classes that need to access the Dispatcher of the UI thread to update bounded lists

Personally, if you need this, I would just save a reference to the Dispatcher, not to the entire UI.

Providing a reference to the Window itself could, potentially, cause confusion.  The intent here is not as clear.

Comment: Thats a good idea. But what is the general practice in that case? All examples I saw assume I am using the Dispatcher from the Window class, not from another class.

Comment: The Dispatcher can be from any UI element.  As a general practice, avoid static members.  With the Dispatcher, you can pass in a member, but you can also get away with doing this once at a top level.  However, I'd probably just set it once on the creation of your first window (or Application), and use it from there...

Comment: If the main goal is just to get access to the Dispatcher, though, I'd strongly suggest storing it - not the Window class.

Answer (score 4):

In the *general* case, it isn't ideal - `static` has some gotchas if you expect threads to be independent, or if you expect garbage collection to collect the window - but arguably you can probably get away with it for you *main* window, since that is probably essentially singleton and lasts the lifetime of the app.

Personally I probably wouldn't - I'd pass it in via a property or constructor argument - but I'm a bit fussy.